# upload_tmp_dir is not set properly - php.ini

Tags: php

I want to upload a file to my server (Apache on RaspberryPi (raspbian) in my home network) over https and then write it to disk with PHP. I'm getting the `move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php2W6AMo' Permission denied` Error. To solve this, I try to change the directory for the temporary upload files, but it's not working properly.

This Code:

```
<?php
ini_set('upload_tmp_dir', '/var/www/upload_tmp_dir/');
echo ini_get('upload_tmp_dir') .'\n';

print_r($_FILES);

$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "It worked.\n";
} else {
    echo "Error!\n";
}

?>
```

produces following output:

```
/var/www/upload_tmp_dir
Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => test.txt
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpq9iDg3
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 124184
        )

)
```

The `php.ini` says this: `/var/www/upload_tmp_dir`. Same for `phpinfo()`.

Why does it still upload the files to `/tmp` ? 
Is there anything I've overseen? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You overlooked that the [“changeable” column in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads) says `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` …

Comment: I edited the php.ini file, the ini_set() was just another try. Nonetheless it's not working.